# Converting cell value to table name to use in charts

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with a few Tables i.e. Art, Drama, English etc.  I want to create a dynamic chart so when I change cell B1 to Art the chart automatically picks up the table Art.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you are asking for but maybe good enough:
Set up data series as in the picture and use the filter in the graph
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks W_O_L_F ended up using your suggestion and using this very helpful post on how to create dynamic named ranges https://www.thinkoutsidetheslide.com/how-to-create-an-excel-chart-with-a-dynamic-range-that-you-select/.